# Spending and left over amount/percentages

Tags: arithmetic, percentages, percentile

**Question 1)** Cam would like to spend some of his money on friends. Of the $350$ dollar budget he was given, he has to spend $75.00$ dollars on office supplies, $10.00$ dollars per person for an entrance fee to the concert that his top $3$ friends and himself will attend later this month, and $17.00$ dollars for pizza for his lunch tomorrow. How much money does that leave for me to spend on each of his $12$ friends?

A) $16.17$ B) $18.17$ C) $19.16$ D) $20.00$ E) $218.00$

I added $(75)+(10*4)(17)=132$

Then $350-132=218$ which would give us E) $218.00$

I thought about it said each of his friends. Does that mean $218.00/12=18.17$ which would give us B) $18.17$

I wanted to know is there an easy way to think about this and what would be the answer. Can someone please help me?

**Question 2)** If you increase your current score of $85%$ by $7%$, what score will you have?

A) $90.5$ B) $90.85$ C) $90.95$ D) $91%$ E) $91.25$

I added $(0.85) + 7%$ which gave me $90.95$ percent. I wanted to know if this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1. He spends more on the three friends then he does on the other 9. he spends 30 dollars on them. On top we have he spends 75 dollars + 17 dollars on himself. So we have the budjet for  each friend to be $((350-75-17-30)/12)=19$, but remember that 3 of his 12 friends receive an extra 10 dollars so each friend receives $(3*29+9*19)/12=21.5$ dollars on average. Since these are neither of the options I would go with B and state the question is not well stated it is unkown who he spends the 75 or 17 dollars on.

Question 2. the proper way to do this is $(.85)*(1.07)=90.95$ i.e. current probability times the probability gained.

Comment: The way I read question 1 is that we are being asked how much money Cam has left to spend on his twelve friends after he has spent $\$75$ on office supplies, $\$40$ on concert tickets, and $\$17$ on lunch.  Therefore, we do not need to subtract the $\$30$ he has already spent on his three closest friends.